# Get tables size info from all databases from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this script which will give me table sizes for a particular databases.

My question is how to rewrite the code so it can return all tables sizes info from SQL Server regardless of what databases, meaning to say I don't need to change `use_db`.

```
[use_db]
SELECT t.name AS TableName,
       p.rows AS RowCounts,
       SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB,
       SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB,
       (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.object_id > 255
GROUP BY t.name,
         p.rows
ORDER BY t.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#space') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #space

CREATE TABLE #space (
      [db_name] SYSNAME
    , obj_name SYSNAME
    , total_pages BIGINT
    , used_pages BIGINT
    , total_rows BIGINT
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #space ([db_name], obj_name, total_pages, used_pages, total_rows)
    SELECT DB_NAME(), SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + ''.'' + o.name, t.total_pages, t.used_pages, t.total_rows
    FROM (
        SELECT
              i.[object_id]
            , total_pages = SUM(a.total_pages)
            , used_pages = SUM(a.used_pages)
            , total_rows = SUM(CASE WHEN i.index_id IN (0, 1) AND a.[type] = 1 THEN p.[rows] END)
        FROM sys.indexes i
        JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.index_id = p.index_id
        JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
        WHERE i.is_disabled = 0
            AND i.is_hypothetical = 0
        GROUP BY i.[object_id]
    ) t
    JOIN sys.objects o ON t.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    WHERE o.name NOT LIKE ''dt%''
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND o.type = ''U''
        AND o.[object_id] > 255;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT 
      [db_name]
    , obj_name
    , total_rows
    , total_space = CAST(total_pages * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    , used_space = CAST(used_pages * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    , unused_space = CAST((total_pages - used_pages) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
FROM #space
```

output -

```
db_name                    obj_name                           total_rows  total_space   used_space   unused_space
-------------------------- ---------------------------------- ----------- ------------- ------------ --------------
master                     dbo.Person                         1000        0.20          0.13         0.08
master                     dbo.Building                       4           0.03          0.03         0.00
ReportServer$SQL_2012      dbo.Keys                           1           0.02          0.02         0.00
ReportServer$SQL_2012      dbo.History                        0           0.00          0.00         0.00
ReportServer$SQL_2012      dbo.ConfigurationInfo              20          0.03          0.03         0.00
ReportServer$SQL_2012      dbo.Catalog                        1           0.08          0.08         0.00
ReportServer$SQL_2012      dbo.UpgradeInfo                    1           0.02          0.02         0.00
```

Comment: hi , is this will return result in MB ? total_space = CAST(total_pages * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this.  You could use the undocumented SQL Server procedure msForEachDb.  It executes the passed SQL statement against each db on the current instance.  The question mark is replaced with the current db name.

For Each Db Example

```
/* Undocumented sp can loop over every db on the server.
 */
EXECUTE msdb..sp_msForEachDb
    '
        USE [?];

        SELECT DB_NAME();
    '
;
```

The trouble with this approach is it is undocumented.  That means MS could withdraw or change the SP at any time.

An alternative, and probably safer approach, is to query the system catalogs.  You can use these to build a dynamic SQL statement that can be executed.

System Catalog Example

```
/* Using system tables to obtain and query each db,
 * via dynamic SQL statement.
 */
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)  = '';

SELECT
    @query = @query + 'USE [' + Name + ']; SELECT DB_NAME();'
FROM
    sys.databases
;

EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSql @query;
;
```

You could also achieve the same result in SSIS or using a [WHILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178642.aspx) loop or [CURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180169.aspx).